# Was vs Were in list with number disagreement

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, lists

I'm unsure whether to use 'was' or 'were' in describing this list.

> There [was/were] food, games, performances, and much more.

I want to divide the list down singular vs plural lines:

> There were games and performances, and there was food and much more.

But this feels unwieldy. Is there a more elegant way to keep the list intact?

Comment: Have you tried to research this topic? If you google “compound subject”, e.g., you’ll find plenty of advice about subject-verb agreement, even with “existential there”.

Comment: Hi, Bryan. The usual agreement is with the number of the first noun in the coordination. _There **was food**, games, performances, and much more_ / _There **were** **games** and performances, and there **was food** and much more_.

Comment: Thank you! I did try doing some searches first, but the phrasing was eluding me for some reason and I was only turning up simple examples.

Comment: The best advice I can give is this.  English is an uninflected language, which nevertheless has some differences in the form of nouns and verbs between singular and plural.  So avoid the sorts of dilemma you mention, if you can,  Find another way round it.  The first point is that the clash comes because you put the singular "food" first.  So the reader's brain has been primed to expect a plural.  So reading a singular will jar a bit.  But if you put it last, or even in the middle, the brain has been a plural noun and won't notice a singular on the way through.

Comment: @BryanArneson The syntactic phenomenon that I referred to is called the concept of 'proximity'. I don't see any problems with your examples.